# Background color is being applied just fine to everything but the header, and I have no idea why

Tags: html, css

I have a grid with a header, nav, content, footer, and space for ads on the side. I am trying to color code each area for now so I can visually see what I am doing and I can't seem to get the header to change color. Every other section is being changed just fine. Not only can I not change the background of the section, but I can't change the text color, or change anything it seems. Thanks for all of the help and here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<style>

* {
    font-family: Arial;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;

}

#grid-container {
    background-color: lightgray;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 15% 42.5% 42.5%;
    grid-template-rows: 20% 15% 45% 20%;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header header header"
      "nav nav nav"
      "advert content content"
      "advert footer footer";
}

#header {
    background-color: yellow;
    grid-area: header;
}

#nav {
    background-color: purple;
    grid-area: nav;
}

#content {
    background-color: blue;
    grid-area: content;
}

#advert {
    background-color: green;
    grid-area: advert;
}

#footer {
    background-color: red;
    grid-area: footer;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="grid-container">
    <head id="header">
        header
    </head>

    <nav id="nav">
        nav
    </nav>

    <main id="content">
        content
    </main>

    <aside id="advert">
        advert
        <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </aside>

    <footer id="footer">
        footer
    </footer>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you make a code snippet please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an `<head>` when you probably meant to use `<header>`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I feel so embarrassed when I manage to make small mistakes like this and then ask for help. I keep getting those mixed up, head, header, ect. Thanks.